# Renewing JQuery variables on each instance of element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to run a piece of JQuery on a div class called .menuwithimage. Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $(".menuwithimage .inner h2").html();
    var text = $(".menuwithimage .inner h2 a").html();

    $(link).insertBefore(".menuwithimage .inner");
    $(".menuwithimage .inner h2 a").replaceWith(text);
    $(".menuwithimage a").empty();
});
```

This code works perfect on the first instance, however the variables don't renew when another instance of this div has appeared, so it inserts content from the first div of that class name that it came across into the subsequent divs of the same class.

Is there a way to re-run this code as new for each instance so it's not picking up old variable data? I've tried using .each, $.each() and while as advised on previous topics, but can't quite get it to work.

I'd really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks in advance!

Markup here: http://jsfiddle.net/rn15vfn3/

Comment: _another instance of this div_  how you are adding these instances?

Comment: any chance of some markup as well? or a live example (in something like http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi, Sorry I've added the markup here: http://jsfiddle.net/rn15vfn3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap your code into each loop (because you want to process all `.menuwithimage`):

```
$(".menuwithimage").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find(".inner h2").html();
    var text = $(this).find(".inner h2 a").html();

    $(link).insertBefore($(this).find(".inner"));

    $(this).find(".inner h2 a").replaceWith(text);
    $(this).find("a").empty();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rn15vfn3/1/

Using `$(this).find(...)` you select necessary elements within individual `.menuwithimage` blocks.

You can also make your code simpler:

```
$(".menuwithimage").each(function() {
    var $link = $(this).find(".inner h2 a");
    $(this).find(".inner h2").text($link.text());
    $link.prependTo(this).empty();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rn15vfn3/2/

Comment: Perfect! The simplified code - even better. Thank you very much.